# How can I add two property in my model in EF code first from one model?

Tags: entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, code-first

I want to add two properties from the city model:

after migration this **error** shows up:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
> 'City.Orders' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure
> the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
> attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

here is my code :

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual City FromCity { get; set; }
    public virtual City ToCity { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose your model is more complicated than just `FromCity` and `ToCity` because I don't think it's a good idea to store such information in a different table. Yet, You can use inheritance in this case.

The table-per-hierarchy (TPH) pattern is used by default to map the [inheritance in EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance). TPH stores the data for all types in the hierarchy in a single table.

However, for your scenario, you can have a base class that holds all related attributes.

```
public class CityBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

Then suppose you need two entities as per your scenario:

```
public class FromCity : CityBase
{
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = null!;
}
public class ToCity : CityBase
{
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And the order entity:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string OrderTitle { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public virtual FromCity FromCity { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual ToCity ToCity { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

This approach can solve your problem with a One-to-Many relationship between `Orders` and `FromCity`, `ToCity` as per below diagram:

[image: Relationship Diagram]